# ZXing Android intent method customize screen

Tags: android, android-intent, zxing

I'm using the intent method to call the barcode scanning app, I'm wondering if it's possible to customize the scanning screen (eg. add a Cancel button on the bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. You can customize the prompt message and a few other aspects of behavior though. Look at the `Intents` class to find keys for parameters you can set in your `Intent` including the prompt message key.